# How to configure IIS 7.5 to accept request for .json file with 'POST' method

Tags: json, iis-7.5

Ive added a MIME type to on idesktop to IIS 7.5 so that it now accepts and responds to 'GET' requests for .json files.  This works fine.

But I also need to accept requests for requests with the method 'POST'

I tried adding additioanl handler to the ISAPI module and ticked the box to accept all verbs but no different.  Really banging my head against the wall now as this was straight forward in IIS 6.

[image]

Here is the response from in firebug

```
    Cache-Control   private
    Allow           GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
    Server          Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
    Date            Wed, 15 Feb 2012 11:16:34 GMT
    Content-Length   5669
```

The response status is Method Not Allowed 405

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking for this as well..

Comment: I know its quite old topic , but have u find any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

The question is - why do you want to have a 'POST' request to a JSON file?
By .json file, do you mean you want to cater static file containing JSON data or an ASP.NET content?

By the looks of the mapping done by you, it seems you have actually added a Handler Mapping, and not MIME type.
For instruction to add MIME type in IIS7.5, please refer to the following link - http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

Comment: That's incorrect, the question is not 'why do you want to..." - the question is "How to configure IIS..."